# Can I combine a list of #ID's into one single class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have 12 #ID's and want to add the same CSS to all of them.
I cannot add classes to these ID's.

So what I want to do is:

`.class-grouped = #ID1, #ID2, #ID3`

My code will be very messy if I have to write all 12 #ID's on all the styles.

Comment: 12 ID's isn't too much, simply need to write them once. Something you will also have to do in case you are able to group them

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add the class in JS:

```js
var ids = ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'];
ids.forEach(function(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).classList.add('class-grouped');
});
```

```css
.class-grouped { background: blue; margin-bottom: 5px; height: 10px; }
```

```html
<div id="ID1"></div>
<div id="ID2"></div>
<div id="ID3"></div>
<div id="ID4"></div>
```

Comment: and why not simply `#ID1,#ID2,#ID3,#ID4 { ... }`? it will be less of code and without JS

Comment: @TemaniAfif the question was how to group them in a class where you can't edit html, this how you do this in JS. Nothing wrong with `#ID1,#ID2,#ID3,#ID4` but that's not the question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("#a, #b, #c, #d");
elements.forEach(elem => elem.classList.add("myClass"));
```

```html
<div id="a">23</div>
<div id="b">232</div>
<div id="c">434</div>
<div id="d">43242</div>
```